# Getting Heroku logs for past few weeks

Tags: heroku, logging

I'm trying to get the production logs for the past few weeks off of heroku but when I do heroku logs, it just returns a few lines showing the production log for today.

Any way to get heroku logs for the past few weeks?

Thanks.

Comment: damn i could really do with those logs... now I'm in trouble...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Correcting my own old response) Previously, Heroku only provided you with access to the last 100 lines. Now this limit apppears to have [been raised](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging).

There's also this pretty cool sounding [logentries](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logentries) addon, with generous free offerings.

Comment: Yep, there is no way around this. Better logging solutions is one thing the company is working on for the near future, however.

Comment: yea, just confirmed the same from heroku support

Comment: not true anymore. You can specify using -n flag how many lines you wish to see

Answer (score 14):

Any number up to 500 lines can now be retrieved using the -n flag.

```
heroku logs -n 420
```

As well you can also run:

```
heroku logs -t
```

And let that run for a while.

EDIT: And you can use third party tools like papertrail. See : [papertrail link](http://help.papertrailapp.com/discussions/questions/18-heroku-setup)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about going back given their limitations - but going forward you can forward your logs to an external syslog server.

[Syslog drains - Premium Add-on](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)